# Ошибка cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset

Tags: sql, delphi

При выполнении следующего кода:

```
procedure TForm4.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: Integer;
begin
  a := DM.ADOQuery9.RecNo;
  user := LoggedOnUserNameEx(3);
  DM.ADOQuery9.Active := False;
  DM.ADOQuery9.SQL.Clear;
  DM.ADOQuery9.SQL.Text := 'Select * from Application where (Status=' +
    QuotedStr('Открыта') + ' or Status=' + QuotedStr('В процессе') + ')' +
    ' and (Account=' + QuotedStr(user) + ')';
  DM.ADOQuery9.Active := true;
  DM.ADOQuery9.RecNo := a;
end;
end.
```

выскакивает ошибка:

> ADOQuery9. cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset

Так и не нашел места в коде, где я должен открыть набор данных для редактирования, или я вообще не туда копаю?

Comment: На какой строке возникает ошибка?

Comment: Не показывает на какой строке

Comment: Перед запуском таймера `ADOQuery9` открывается?

Comment: Да, открывается перед запуском формы

Comment: Нажмите Break в окне сообщения и посмотрите на какую строку попадете

Comment: raise EDatabaseError.Create(Format('%s: %s', [Component.Name, Message])) вот здесь в другом модуле

Comment: Нашел ошибку, всем спасибо. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Ваш вопрос бесполезен для сообщества. Либо опубликуйте ответ, либо удалите его

Comment: Тут ошибка сама за себя говорит - есть 100500 мест где идет обращение к `ADOQuery9` и в какой то момент при обращении - он закрыт.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй

```
  form1.ADOQuery1.Close;
  form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select * from Application where (Status=' +
QuotedStr('Открыта') + ' or Status=' + QuotedStr('В процессе') + ')' +
' and (Account=' + QuotedStr(user) + ');
  form1.ADOQuery1.Open;
  form1.ClientDataSet1.Refresh;
```

Comment: `ADOQuery1.Text = ''` Делает `Close` и перезаписывает существующие данные, так что заменяет `Clear` и `Add`. `QuotedStr...` - Потенциально опасные места, нужно использовать параметры.